# Multiply data according to the numbers I want

Tags: excel, vba

I am a little bit confused about how to fix this code.

what was happening to this is I always keep writing a number in pop up box instead doing that I want to click the weight "range multiply button" and multiply directly instead typing text in the pop up button 
[image]

so I made an example 
Repro:

```
1st I pasted the highlight blue  
2nd I have select the range which I want to multiply
3rd I click the weight range multiply 
4th Since I want to multiply it to three so  
    I type three in the pop-up box and and click **OK** 
    so the the result can be found in the highlighted in RED

So this time 
What I want to happen is that 
1st I will select the blue 
2nd I will click the button **weight range multiply** 
    it will automatically multiply in to 3 and the 3 is referring to some 
    specific cells(let say column **G**).
```

can someone help me with that? and Thanks in advance

This is the code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim NumberMe As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Set oRng = Selection
oRng.Copy
NumberMe = InputBox("Multiply by?")
For i = 1 To NumberMe
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you so much in advance guys

Comment: You want to select range and multiply each number in selected range by inputted number, in this case by 3?

Comment: The code was design to multiply the selected cells for example the highlighted in blue... that column is for count from and count to so everytime I click the button Weight range multiply there is a pop up message where did you put the number 3 in order to multiply or clone 3 times according to the highlighted in red. where you can see in the screensshot

Comment: so this time what I want to happen is everytime I highlight it the blue one and click the weight range multiply button there is no more pop up message where I will putting the number 3 but it will just eventually referring to some specific cell to multiply/clone the blue one and the result will be the red..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I got your point, but as I have understood you need to copy (not multiply) your range of data certain amount of times. I can't see your cell position, as it is cut from your screenshot.

Your number 3 is in cell `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").Value` in my example. My data is in `A3:B17`, so we are specifying starting cell by `Set StartCell = Range("A3")`

Here is the code that will copy your range certain amount of times:

```
Sub CommandButton()

    Dim NumberMe As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set StartCell = Range("A3")

    NumberMe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").Value

    'Find Last Row and Column
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Copy Range
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy

    For i = 1 To NumberMe
        sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next

End Sub
```

You can edit it according to your needs.

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to select range until column *number*. Try this one (replace `sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy`) by:

```
sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Copy
```

In this case column number is 2. Then you don't need `LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` and `Dim LastColumn` - can be removed from code.

Final result will look like:

```
Sub CommandButton()

    Dim NumberMe As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set StartCell = Range("A3")

    NumberMe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").Value

    'Find Last Row
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy Range
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Copy

    For i = 1 To NumberMe
        sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Sir you're correct you're amazing thanks a lot for helping me I am looking for this code so for so many times and Just found here in stackoverflow.. thank you so much Sir.

Comment: Bro Can I ask something I just try the code and it seems I found that it will apply to the whole row so what if I only want to copy the row cells from A-C only is that possible? I am really sorry I am just new in here can you help me with that?

Comment: Now its correct Sir Now I know where did some changes came from thank you so much for this I am so happy...

Comment: You can also use different options for pasting depending on your data (I mean `xlPasteValues`). Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype
Also try to build your question as short and productive as possible, Otherwise people will downvote them. I have went the same way when I have registered here, tho.

Comment: Oh! thank you so much for your advise Sir I will do it next time... and thank you for the link you gave this will help me a lot to my automation macro population.... you're great!